# What are the change in the iOS API for Core Data between iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0? Where can I find them?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

What are the change in the iOS API for Core Data between iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0? Where can I find them?

I am having trouble finding anything on Apple's site that can show me the changes between iOS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the ["What's new in iOS 5 page"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1) and search for Core Data.  Not much is new.  You'll need a registered developer account for access to that page, I believe.

And [here is a list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011042) of specific API differences, though it's all of them so you would have to look for the Core Data change that you are interest in.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent roundup of changes in CoreData is this blog post:
http://oleb.net/blog/2011/08/whats-new-for-developers-in-lion-part-3/

It not only sums up, but explains the new CoreData stuff in Lion, that was almost all included in iOS5 a few months later.